# Ngb-dropdown with input field doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-bootstrap

I am working with ngb-dropdown. I tried to add an input field to the dropdown. When I focus on the input field, the popup gets closed.

Is there any way to stay the focus of input and the dropdown to be opened

```
<div ngbDropdown placement="top-right" class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic2" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropup</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic2">
    <button class="dropdown-item">
      <input type="text" />
    </button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4JX2yFA9izPaPelcF9Y?p=preview

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Just linking to another site for **all** your code doesn't work. You really should have an [mcve] here, within your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To stay the focus on the input field and to make dropdown remain open. You need to add:

`[autoClose]="'outside'"` along with `ngbDropdown` directive.

> "outside" - the dropdown will close only on the outside clicks and not on menu clicks.

Here is your file named: dropdown-basic.html replicated successfully

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div ngbDropdown [autoClose]="'outside'" class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
        <button class="dropdown-item">
          <input type="text" />
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col text-right">
    <div ngbDropdown [autoClose]="'outside'" placement="top-right" class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic2" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropup</button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic2">
        <button class="dropdown-item">
          <input type="text" />
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information visit [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/api)